# How could I add a fixed prefix to filename using context menu Item?

Tags: command-line, windows-registry, context-menu, rename

I want to be able to right click on a file or bunch of files and automatically add a prefix(in this case an underscore) to their names.

**What I did**:

I made a registry command at HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT>*>shell

I named it "example"

I made a sub String value and I named it "command"

I change command Value Data to:

```
cmd /c ren "%1" "_%1"
```

whenever I perform this action from context menu **it just opens cmd program and completely ignores the command** I gave it.

Answer (score 0):

You are omitting the parameter `/c`.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490880.aspx

> Syntax
>
> cmd [[{/c|/k}] ... string]
>
> Parameters
>
> /c   : Carries out the command specified by string and then stops.

Comment: I included it but it didn't work after that too.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found a way that indirectly does the job you asked.
install a third party program named [ReNamer](http://www.den4b.com/products/renamer). You can use this file as a command line tool.

So instead of using `cmd ren` command, use

```
Renamer.exe /rename <predefined-preset> "%1"
```

The only thing left to explain is the preset that I referred to.

Open ReNamer software and make a preset as you like (for example preset that will add _ prefix to filename) and save that preset, after that you can safely use that preset in command explained.

So the final command in my Registry Key entry is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\ReNamer\ReNamer.exe" /rename "underscore" "%1"
```